# Ошибка в методе java

Tags: java, исключения, методы

В чем ошибка?

```
private static Weapon_type typeOfWeapon;

public Weapon_type getType(){
    return typeOfWeapon;
}
```

Подчеркивается `Weapon_type` и выводит ошибку:

> The return type is incompatible with Window.getType()

Comment: возвращаемый тип не соответствует тому, что указан в имплементируемом интерфейсе

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что в Вашем классе Вы объявляете метод, который определен в суперклассе Вашего класса: название и список формальных параметров совпадают, однако возвращаемое значение отличается. Этого делать нельзя.

> Хотя возвращаемые типы перегруженных методов могут быть различны, самого возвращаемого типа недостаточно для различения двух версий метода.

Для решения проблемы можете поменять название Вашего метода. Ну или сделать так, чтобы список формальных параметров отличался от списка формальных параметров метода суперкласса (в данном случае, был непустым).